# Unable to connect to Microsoft SQL Server, error 18456

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have created a virtual machine using Google Cloud with SQL Server on Windows server. My server detail as SQL Server 2016 Standard, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, x64 built on 20230414, supports Shielded VM features

All services are working okay but I am unable to connect Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 to SQL Server.

I am getting below error as I start  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18:

> Login failed for user 'BRAVURA\bravuraresort'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: So have you previously logged in with SSMS using the `Administrator` account and created a Windows Logon for the `BRAVURA\bravuraresort` account?

Comment: No sir, i have login with bravuraresort

Comment: Check the SQL Server 's logs for the true authentication error. If you don't understand that error then [edit] your question to include that error. The authentication error passed to the application layer is intentionally vague.

Comment: *"No sir, i have login with bravuraresort"* a SQL Login isn't a windows login; they are two *completely* different authentication methods. If you create a SQL Login, trying to use Windows Credentials won't work.